# Hiding = when rendering inline code snippets in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs in org-mode I can have inline code snippets by enclosing the snippet with the `=` sign. Here is an example:

[image: org-code in Emacs org-mode]

In the example above I have customized the face of `org-code` to make the background darker than the standard text background.

But is there a way to have Emacs **hide** the `=` signs?  It would be great to have something like what org-mode does with links with syntax:

```
  [[link]]
```

where Emacs will display `link` instead of `[[link]]` (see [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-format.html)), and will show the brackets only when you want to edit the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `org-hide-emphasis-markers` to `t`. But note that this will also hide, for example the `\` signs for italics and such.